# Getting 415 content not supported application/pkixcmp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

In my Spring API I am using the following annotations :
`@PostMapping(value = "/api/xyz", consumes = "application/pkixcmp")`

Exception I am getting when consuming API:

`[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/pkixcmp' not supported]`

Comment: this may help; https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-custom-media-type

Answer (score 1):

you add this type in your HttpMessageConverter